# Why firefox shows everything larger than chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

My Firefox shows every element on every site larger than that same page in chrome.
Please look at this pictures:

[image]
[image]

As you can see everything looks larger in Firefox, even the google's doodle.
Both zoom setting are set in 100% and I'm using 64 bit version of both and of course Firefox developer edition. So whats the wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following steps in firefox:

- Type `about:config` in the address bar.
- Accept the conditions
- search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx and double click on it.
- change its value and test it to see if the font size and other things have changed.

Comment: @bobsilon Usual a good value would be like 0.8, but change accordingly.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/804949/why-does-firefox-interpret-100-zoom-differently-to-other-browsers